# How to pass JSON string into my ColdFusion web service and return success/failure message?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, cfc

I am writing a simple RESTful web service (cfc) in ColdFusion and want to pass a JSON string to the same service. Something like this:

I have written something like below:

```
{
"CustomerID": 100,
"UserName": "test",
"Password": "xxxxx",
}
```

Plus I want to return a success/failure messages after validating.
Any idea how should I achieve this?

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/folder">    

<cfscript>
  record=deserializeJSON(
'{
"CustomerID": 100,
"UserName": "aimsweb",
"Password": "xxxxx",
}'
);

</cfscript>


<cffunction name="UserDetails" returnType="JSON" access="remote" HttpMethod="GET">

 <cfargument name="Username" type="string" required="Yes">
 <cfargument name="Password" type="string" required="Yes">
 <cfargument name="CustomerID" type="string" required="Yes">

 <cfset Form.CustomerID = arguments.CustomerID>
 <cfset Form.Username = arguments.Username>
 <cfset Form.Password = Hash(arguments.Password)>


<cfquery name="AW1Users" datasource="#request.app.dsn#">
        SELECT * FROM tableName where UserName='xxxx'
</cfquery>  


    <cfif AW1Users.RecordCount>
            <cfthrow errorcode="200"                 
                    detail="Success"
                    message="Success"
                    type="Application">

    <cfelseif AW1Users.CustomerID NEQ form.CustomerID>
            <cfthrow errorcode="400"                 
                    detail="Customer Id doesn't exist"
                    message="Customer Id doesn't exist"
                    type="Application">                 
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn AW1Users>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return cfheader in restful webservice. for example

Unauthorized:

`<cfheader  statusCode = "401" statusText = "unauthorized">`

OR

`<cfheader  statusCode = "401" statusText = "Customer Id doesn't exist">`

Authorized:

`<cfheader  statusCode = "200" statusText = "Authorized">`

OR

`<cfheader  statusCode = "200" statusText = "Success">`

Helpful url for coldfusion restful webservice:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html

JSON:

```
    <cfquery datasource="xxx" name="qGetRecords">
        select userId, login, email from users limit 0,3
    </cfquery>

    <cfset dataset = [] />

    <cfloop query="qGetRecords">
        <cfset record = {} />
        <cfset record["one"] = qGetRecords.userId />
        <cfset record["two"] = qGetRecords.login />
        <cfset record["three"] = qGetRecords.email />
        <cfset ArrayAppend(dataset, record) />
    </cfloop>

<!--- You can return this JSON  -->  
    <cfoutput>
        <p>#SerializeJSON(qGetRecords)#</p>
        <p>#SerializeJSON(dataset)#</p>
    </cfoutput>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: But any idea how should I pass the JSON to this web service?